# Excel VBA - Copy pictures from on sheet to another in specified location

Tags: excel, vba

I'be built a code for a calendar-type plan with textboxes and pictures. I've managed to make a code so the shapes are all placed on the right spot. However, I'm struggling to copy some pictures from one sheet to another.

```
Sub AddEvent2()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim i As Integer, shp As Shape, s, s2, v, t1, t2, t3, h, p, w, rgb1, rgbULP, rgbPULP, rgbSPULP, rgbXLSD, rgbALPINE, rgbJET, rgbSLOPS As String

For Each shp In Sheets("Calendar").Shapes
   shp.Delete
Next shp

For i = 4 To 21
    
    t1 = Sheets("AdminSheet").Cells(i, 30).Value 'Cell location on Calendar
    s = Sheets("AdminSheet").Cells(i, 29).Value 'Naming the shapebox
    w = Sheets("AdminSheet").Cells(i, 28).Value 'Supplier
    p = Sheets("AdminSheet").Cells(i, 27).Value 'Product
    t2 = Sheets("AdminSheet").Cells(i - 1, 30).Value 'Next Cell location on Calendar
    v = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Sheets("AdminSheet").Cells(i, 24).Value, "hh:mm") & " " & _
    Sheets("AdminSheet").Cells(i, 25).Value & Sheets("AdminSheet").Cells(i, 26).Value & " " & Sheets("AdminSheet").Cells(i, 27).Value 'Text in shapebox

    rgbULP = rgb(177, 160, 199)
    rgbPULP = rgb(255, 192, 0)
    rgbSPULP = rgb(0, 112, 192)
    rgbXLSD = rgb(196, 189, 151)
    rgbALPINE = rgb(196, 215, 155)
    rgbJET = rgb(255, 255, 255)
    rgbSLOPS = rgb(255, 0, 0)
    
    If s <> "" Then
    Sheets("Calendar").Select
    If i > 4 And t2 = t1 Then
        s2 = Sheets("AdminSheet").Cells(i - 1, 29).Value 'Name of the added shapebox
        h = Sheets("Calendar").Shapes.Range(Array(s2)).Height 'Height of the added shapebox
        t3 = Sheets("Calendar").Shapes.Range(Array(s2)).Top 'Top of the added shapebox
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Sheets("Calendar").Range(t1).Left + 1.5, 3 + t3 + h, 209, 36.6).Select
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Sheets("Calendar").Range(t1).Left + 1.5, Sheets("Calendar").Range(t1).Top + 3, 209, 36.6).Select
    End If
    
    With Selection
        .Name = s
        With .ShapeRange
            .IncrementLeft 0
            .IncrementTop 0
            With .Fill
                .Visible = msoTrue
                If p = "ULP" Then
                    .ForeColor.rgb = rgbULP
                ElseIf p = "PULP" Then
                    .ForeColor.rgb = rgbPULP
                ElseIf p = "SPULP" Then
                    .ForeColor.rgb = rgbSPULP
                ElseIf p = "XLSD" Then
                    .ForeColor.rgb = rgbXLSD
                ElseIf p = "ALPINE" Then
                    .ForeColor.rgb = rgbALPINE
                ElseIf p = "JET" Then
                    .ForeColor.rgb = rgbJET
                ElseIf p = "SLOPS" Then
                    .ForeColor.rgb = rgbSLOPS
                End If
                .Transparency = 0
                .Solid
            End With
            
            With .TextFrame2
                .MarginLeft = 5.7
                .MarginRight = 38.6
                .AutoSize = msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText
                    With .TextRange.Font
                                .NameComplexScript = "Lucida Console"
                                .NameFarEast = "Lucida Console"
                                .Name = "Lucida Console"
                                .Size = 14
                            
                    End With
                    .TextRange.Characters.Text = v
            End With
        End With
    End With
    
    Sheets("AdminSheet").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(w)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Calendar").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.ShapeRange.Name = w & s
    Selection.Name = w & s
    Sheets("Calendar").Shapes(w & s).Top = Sheets("Calendar").Shapes(s).Top + (Sheets("Calendar").Shapes(s).Height / 2) - (Sheets("Calendar").Shapes(w & s).Height / 2)
    Sheets("Calendar").Shapes(w & s).Left = Sheets("Calendar").Shapes(s).Left + Sheets("Calendar").Shapes(s).Width - Sheets("Calendar").Shapes(w & s).Width
    
    End If

Next i
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

As you can see I'm very new to coding... Anyway, what I'm trying to do is to copy a pic named after "w" and paste it to the right side of the added Textbox (within the box - I guess the location would be textbox.left + textbox.width - pic.width but it doesn't work). I've tried recording it but it doesn't work for me. Any ideas?
*Edit - I updated the with the code I use for that task and the error I get. The location is wrong as well - they go outside the textbox...

I also struggle to understand how to change the fillcolor.RGB of the shape dynamically. I made it work with "if" statement but looks ugly. Any ideas how to sort the code there? Why `.ForeColor.RGB = "rgb" & p` not working?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

On the initial code, the name of the picture I was copying was not changing, hence not unique on the Sheet. So, when I was tying to move the `Shape("example")`, I was moving all with the same name.

Anyway, code updated with name change variable!